# Trouble with member function pointer as template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic

The commented-out line in the code below won't compile because type `F` does not meet the specialization.  Can someone explain why?

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>

template <typename R, typename T, typename... Args>
std::function<R(Args...)> memoizeMemberFunction (R T::*f(Args...), const T* t) {
    auto cache = std::make_shared<std::map<std::tuple<const T*, Args...>, R>>();
    return ([f, cache](T* t, Args... args) {
        const std::tuple<const T*, Args...> tuple(t, args...);
        if (cache->find(tuple) == cache->end())
            (*cache)[tuple] = (t->*f)(args...);  // Insert 'tuple' as a new key in the map *cache.
        return (*cache)[tuple];
    });
}

template <typename Class, typename Fptr, Fptr> struct MemberFunctionMemoizer;

template <typename Class, typename R, typename... Args, R Class::*F(Args...)>
struct MemberFunctionMemoizer<Class, R (Class::*)(Args...) const, F> {
    static std::function<R(Class*, Args...)>& get (const Class* p) {
        static std::function<R (Args...)> memoizedF (memoizeMemberFunction(F, p)); 
        return memoizedF;
    }
};

struct FibonacciCalculator {
    unsigned long calculate(unsigned num) const {
        using F = MemberFunctionMemoizer<FibonacciCalculator,
            unsigned long (FibonacciCalculator::*)(unsigned) const, &FibonacciCalculator::calculate>;
//      return (num < 2) ? num : F::get(this)(num - 1) + F::get(this)(num - 2);
        // Won't compile because F does not meet the specialization.
    }
};

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    FibonacciCalculator fib;
    std::cout << fib.calculate(10) << '\n';
}
```

Am I missing something here?  How to get `F` to meet the specialization?  I tried removing the const qualifiers out of the picture, but the same problem persists.

I also want to maintain the design of using a member function pointer as template argument, even though there is a solution to this particular problem by using a non-member function pointer.

Comment: constness. The member function pointer template argument is not const-qualified. Also, I think `R Class::*F(Args...)` is not a pointer-to-member-function.

Comment: I tried adjusting the constness, including making `calculate()` non-const, and still get the same problem.  How to fix that?

Comment: I think `R Class::*F(Args...)` is a function that returns a pointer-to-member, i.e. `auto F(Args...) -> R Class::*`. OTOH, `R (Class::*F)(Args...)` is a pointer-to-member-function, that can be const-qualified.

Comment: Something seems still to be wrong with your memoization, though: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8c47b31b8a0c3a0

Comment: I don't quite understand some parts of your code, I've tried to fix it in a way that made.. some sense to me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03f07a4f126cea06 Hope that helps.

Comment: Basically, my advice is to avoid using pointers-to-member-functions directly. Wrap them in some `integral_constant`-like struct with proper `operator()` access, and then use them as ordinary function objects with a leading `this` parameter.

Comment: Remark: `num` is `unsigned` and `calculate` returns an `unsigned long`. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue you have is the fact that you're trying to memoize a function of signature:

```
unsigned long calculate();
```

but you're calling the memoization cache's returned function `F::get(this)` with `num - 1` or `num - 2`.

In other words: memoization relies on the fact that "function called with identical arguments yields identical return value" but the function you're memoizing doesn't take any parameters (nothing wrong with that in itself) but then you shouldn't pass it any parameters either.

Your current FibonacciCalculator class cannot use memoization, as it is currently implemented.

I have made an implementation that sort of *might* do what you hoped; it computes Fibonacci numbers *and* it memoizes the memberfunction call ...
Note: there's extra 'noise' in the `memoizeMemberFunction()` but that's output to show that it's working - you'll see in the output that function calls are used twice and computed only once.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>

template <typename R, typename T, typename... Args>
std::function<R(Args...)> memoizeMemberFunction (R (T::*f)(Args...), T* t) {
    auto cache = std::make_shared<std::map<std::tuple<T*, Args...>, R>>();
    return [f, t, cache](Args... args) {
        const std::tuple<T*, Args...> tuple(t, args...);
        if (cache->find(tuple) == cache->end()) {
            (*cache)[tuple] = (t->*f)(args...);  // Insert 'tuple' as a new key in the map *cache.
            std::cout << "Computed f(";
            int dummy[sizeof...(Args)] = { (std::cout << args << ", ", 0)... };
            std::cout << ") = " << (*cache)[tuple] << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "Using f(";
        int dummy[sizeof...(Args)] = { (std::cout << args << ", ", 0)... };
        std::cout << ") = " << (*cache)[tuple] << std::endl;
        return (*cache)[tuple];
    };
}

struct FibonacciCalculator {
    unsigned long num;
    unsigned long calculate(unsigned long n = (unsigned long)-1) {
        static auto memoizedF (memoizeMemberFunction(&FibonacciCalculator::calculate, this));
        if( n==(unsigned long)-1 )
            return memoizedF(num);
        return (n < 2) ? n : memoizedF(n-1) + memoizedF(n-2);
    }
};

int main() {
    FibonacciCalculator fib{ 10 };
    std::cout << fib.calculate() << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to dyp for correcting my horrible struggle with syntax, I have accomplished what I set out to do:

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>

template <typename R, typename T, typename... Args>
std::function<R(Args...)> memoizeMemberFunction (R (T::*f)(Args...), T* t) {
    auto cache = std::make_shared<std::map<std::tuple<T*, Args...>, R>>();
    return ([f, cache, t](Args... args) {
        const std::tuple<T*, Args...> tuple(t, args...);
        if (cache->find(tuple) == cache->end())
            (*cache)[tuple] = (t->*f)(args...);  // Insert 'tuple' as a new key in the map *cache.
        return (*cache)[tuple];
    });
}

template <typename R, typename T, typename... Args>
std::function<R(Args...)> memoizeConstMemberFunction (R (T::*f)(Args...) const, const T* t) {
    auto cache = std::make_shared<std::map<std::tuple<const T*, Args...>, R>>();
    return ([f, cache, t](Args... args) {
        const std::tuple<const T*, Args...> tuple(t, args...);
        if (cache->find(tuple) == cache->end())
            (*cache)[tuple] = (t->*f)(args...);  // Insert 'tuple' as a new key in the map *cache.
        return (*cache)[tuple];
    });
}

template <typename Class, typename Fptr, Fptr> struct MemberFunctionMemoizer;
template <typename Class, typename Fptr, Fptr> struct ConstMemberFunctionMemoizer;

template <typename Class, typename R, typename... Args, R (Class::*F)(Args...) const>
struct ConstMemberFunctionMemoizer<Class, R (Class::*)(Args...) const, F> {
    static std::function<R(Args...)>& get (const Class* p) {
        static std::function<R (Args...)> memoizedF (memoizeConstMemberFunction(F, p)); 
        return memoizedF;
    }
};

template <typename Class, typename R, typename... Args, R (Class::*F)(Args...)>
struct MemberFunctionMemoizer<Class, R (Class::*)(Args...), F> {
    static std::function<R(Args...)>& get (Class* p) {
        static std::function<R (Args...)> memoizedF (memoizeMemberFunction(F, p)); 
        return memoizedF;
    }
};

// Testing
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct FibonacciCalculator {
    std::vector<unsigned long> computed;
    unsigned long calculate (unsigned num) const {
        using F = ConstMemberFunctionMemoizer<FibonacciCalculator, unsigned long (FibonacciCalculator::*)(unsigned) const, &FibonacciCalculator::calculate>;  // 'decltype(&FibonacciCalculator::calculate)' can be used in place of 'unsigned long (FibonacciCalculator::*)(unsigned) const'.
        return (num < 2) ? num : F::get(this)(num - 1) + F::get(this)(num - 2);
    }
    unsigned long calculateAndStore (unsigned num) {
        using F = MemberFunctionMemoizer<FibonacciCalculator, unsigned long (FibonacciCalculator::*)(unsigned), &FibonacciCalculator::calculateAndStore>;  // 'decltype(&FibonacciCalculator::calculateAndStore)' can be used in place of 'unsigned long (FibonacciCalculator::*)(unsigned)'.
        const unsigned long result = (num < 2) ? num : F::get(this)(num - 1) + F::get(this)(num - 2);
        computed.push_back(result);
        return result;
    }
};

int main() {
    FibonacciCalculator fib;
    for (unsigned i = 1; i < 20; i++)
        std::cout << fib.calculate(i) << ' ';  // 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181
    std::cout << '\n';

    for (unsigned i = 1; i < 20; i++)
        std::cout << fib.calculateAndStore(i) << ' ';  // 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181
    std::cout << '\n';
    for (unsigned long x : fib.computed)
        std::cout << x << ' ';  // 1 1 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 5 5 8 8 13 13 21 21 34 34 55 55 89 89 144 144 233 233 377 377 610 610 987 987 1597 1597 2584 2584 4181
    std::cout << '\n';  
}
```